# Make a turn in a long line of coding in SAS program

Tags: sas

I have a very long line in SAS coding because there are so many variables that needed to include. How to make a turn to shorten the line and wrap to another line in SAS?

Comment: Basically, you can add line break where there is a valid space.

Comment: If you use the SASjs lint you can force (through git hooks) particular line lengths.

Personally I aim for 80 chars max.  Here's the repo: https://github.com/sasjs/lint

It's used in the SASjs CLI and SASjs VS Code extension (and soon, SASjs Server also)

Answer (score 0):

SAS is semicolon delimited. Just add a return and keep on going. That will work until it reaches a semicolon. What O/S are you using with SAS?

For example, this works:

```
DATA 
TEST;
SET
SASHELP.CLASS;
RUN;
```

The semicolons matter, not the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the @AlanC example taken to the token extreme:

```
DATA 
TEST
;
SET
SASHELP
.
CLASS
;
RUN
;
```